# Message::simbolo uses undefined class Symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, containers, c2079

Error   C2079   'Message::simbolo' uses undefined class 'Symbol'

is generated on this line when compiling

```
    Symbol simbolo;
```

This is my C++ code:

class Message

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Symbol.h"
#include "SharedEditor.h"

class SharedEditor;
class Symbol;


class Message
{
private:
    SharedEditor* sender;
    int action; //1 inserted 2 deleted
    Symbol simbolo;

public:
    Message();
    Message(SharedEditor* sender, Symbol nuovosimbolo, int action);
    ~Message();
};
```

class Symbol

```
#pragma once
#include "SharedEditor.h"
#include <vector>

class SharedEditor;
class Message;

class Symbol
{
    char character;
    int siteID;
    SharedEditor* generator;
    std::vector<int> position;

public:
    Symbol();
    Symbol(char ch, SharedEditor* source, int ID, std::vector<int> pos);
    ~Symbol();

};
```

class SharedEditor:

```
#pragma once
#include "NetworkServer.h"
#include "Message.h"
#include "Symbol.h"


class Message;
class Symbol;


class SharedEditor
{
private:
    NetworkServer& _server;
    int _siteId;
    std::vector<Symbol> _symbols;

   //other functions
public:
    SharedEditor(NetworkServer ns);
    ~SharedEditor();
    void process(const Message& m);
};
```

class NetworkServer:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include "SharedEditor.h"
#include "Message.h"

class SharedEditor;
class Message;


class NetworkServer
{
private:
    std::vector<SharedEditor*> connected;
    std::queue<Message> codaMessaggi;
public:
    int connect(SharedEditor* sharedEditor);
    void disconnect(SharedEditor* sharedEditor);
    void send(const Message& m);
    NetworkServer();
    ~NetworkServer();
};
```

Comment: Why forward declaration `class Symbol;`, even if you are including the definition of a class?

Comment: I got so many unexplained errors wherever `Symbol` was without defining that. I found online that trick.

Comment: What "unexplained errors"? How are those "unexplained errors" worse, than this "unexplained error"? Forward declaration has its uses, and this isn't it. Consider not practicing [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You won't get far with it.

Comment: Deleting `class Symbol` I get 8 error:
'missing identifier', 'sintax error: Symbol identifier', ''simbolo': unknown override indentifier' ect..
I can't explain why..

Comment: Does "SharedEditor.h" include either Symbol.h or Message.h? This smells like a dependency cycle.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzone I hope that you deleted forward declaration, instead of the `class Symbol` in class definition. Please provide [mcve],  that reproduces this error.

Comment: @Botje yes, it includes both

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'll do

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I had to do forward declaration in every class to avoid errors like those mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rework your various header files to break the dependency cycle.
The general rule is: if you only need pointers or references to a type T, you can get away with a forward declaration (`class T;`) instead of a full class declaration (`class T { ... }`, typically behind a `#include`).

For the example above I will go over each file and what you need:

- Symbol.h needs a forward declaration of `SharedEditor`, as it only uses `SharedEditor*`.
- Message.h needs a forward declaration of `SharedEditor`, but a full `#include "Symbol.h"` (compiler needs to know how big a `Symbol` is to calculate the size of `Message`)
- SharedEditor needs a forward declaration of `Message` (passed as a reference), a full `#include "NetworkServer.h"` (passed as a parameter) and a full `#include "Symbol.h"` (used in a vector)
- NetworkServer needs a forward declaration of `SharedEditor` (only used with pointers), but a full `#include "Message.h"` (used in a queue)

If you still have two classes that need full includes of each other, search stack overflow for "C++ dependency cycle" or somesuch.

Comment: Thanksssss a lot! I didn't get the different between `#include` and forward declaration. It works